# Трассировка exe файла

Tags: windows-10, администрирование, доступ, права-доступа

Подскажите программку для получение данных, куда лезит exe файл,в папку, файл реестра  и т. д.
Проблема в том,что запускаю exе и не выполняется без какой либо ошибки и записи в логах.

У нас есть права администратора,но они обераззы в целях информационной безопасности.

Если запустить от имени системной учетной записи, то все работает.

Идея в том,что бы понять где ему не хватает прав для выполнения своей логики

Comment: когда-то следили за исполняемыми файлами утилиты `RegMon` и `FileMon`. Теперь-же, MS завернула их в один флакон `ProcMon` скачать который можно от сюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Спасибо, проверил,то что надо.